# Doctrine Error with Charset (Illegal Mix of collations) - can I change it?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, pdo

I have the problem that all my tables and string fields on my productive database are set to latin1_swedish_ci. I just found out while encountering an error in my log that said:

General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

I use Symfony2 and Doctrine. Not sure why it set it up this way in the beginning, but I am afraid to make things worse when I change them manually. Any help?

Comment: This has been asked many times, I think the solution was to change the desired defaults in mysql, and also ALTER already existing tables.

Comment: If your on a development system, then backup your database, do what ChocoDeveloper says and see what happens. If your on a live system, then create yourself a devsystem.